# Java: Can one get printf to show an enum's name?

Tags: java, enums, printf

I notice that println() does this, but I cannot get it to work in printf().

In the following snippet, the first two println's give RED and BLUE, then the printf crashes.

```
class Jim {
public enum Colours  {BLUE, RED}
static Colours xx = Colours.RED;
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Colours fred = Colours.BLUE;
    System.out.println(xx);
    System.out.println(fred);
    System.out.printf("%d, %d\n", fred, xx);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%d` format specifiers are not compatible with `enum` types unless used against the [`ordinal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) value. To invoke the `enum's` [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29) method (which uses the `name` field) you can use `%s` instead

```
System.out.printf("%s, %s%n", fred, xx);
```

Read: [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)

Comment: That's fine, thanks.  But do you think one day there'll be a %m or something that will denote an enum specifically?  Or is that a daft question?  (I don't know much Java).

Comment: Dont see the need for such a specifier, the %s specifier already displays enums :)

Comment: OK, Reimeus, absolutely true.  But it would be nice, would it not, to say enum when you mean enum.